# Como enviar valor de ViewModel a textbox del view wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

Se tiene una función creada desde la capa core/negocio, que realiza cálculos y el valor  del resultado se necesita que aparezca en un textbox del view...

Este es el textbox:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceWrapper}, 
        Path=RecursosControles.EtiquetaValor, 
        ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=False}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="4" />
```

en mi método action donde llamó la función se tiene así:

```
    private void CalcularAction(object obj)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.DocumentoID))
        {// aca enviar al textbox del view txtValor.text = 
           CalcularConceptoPPA(this.DocumentoID, this.concepto.DiasMes, this.concepto.DiasAtraso, this.concepto.Porcentaje, this.concepto.TipoPPA, this.concepto.TCRM);
        }//.... demas codigo
```

**UPDATE**
este metodo invoca la accion al servicio pero no trae el valor

```
private void CalcularConceptoPPA(string conceptoIDConceptoSTN, int diasMes, int DiasAtraso, double Porcentaje, int tipoPpa, decimal TCRM)
    {
        App.Current.ServicioCalculos.CalcularConceptoPPA(conceptoIDConceptoSTN,  diasMes, DiasAtraso, Porcentaje, tipoPpa, TCRM,
            Calculation =>
            {
                if (Calculation.HasError)
                {
                    this.RiaCallError = Calculation.Error.Message;
                    Calculation.MarkErrorAsHandled();
                }
                if (Calculation.IsComplete)
                {
                    CalcularConceptoPPA_Complete(Calculation.Value);
                }
            }, null);
    }
```

la funcion en la capa de negocio esta definida asi:

```
 public decimal CalcularConceptoPPA(string conceptoIDConceptoSTN, int diasMes, int DiasAtraso, double Porcentaje, int tipoPpa, decimal TCRM)
    {


        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(conceptoIDConceptoSTN))
        {
            return 0;
        }

        try
```

Soy nuevo con wpf, cualquier ayuda es valiosa

Comment: Estas usando MVVM? Has puesto el datacontext de la vista apuntando al viewmodel?

Comment: hola @Pikoh no se está usando datacontext, se está usando desde línea de código el bindeo de todo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se supone que es si estás usando ViewModel o View entonces estás siguiendo el patrón MVVM.
El asunto, para entender, es más o menos así:

Tienes una ventana (view) con un `TextBlock` y una clase **APARTE** que es el ViewModel donde haces los cálculos, pues en la ventana, arriba tienes que agregar el namespace del ViewModel, algo así:

```
<Window x:Class="MiProyecto.Views.MiVentana"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MiProyecto.ViewModels"
x:Name="myWindow" Title="Mi Ventana" Height="480" Width="720"
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Topmost="true"  ResizeMode="CanMinimize" >
    <Window.Resources> 
        <vm:MyViewModel  x:Key="MyVM"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource MyVM}">
        <!-- TODA TU VENTANA -->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Con eso tu ventana ya sabe de donde tiene que sacar los datos que muestra.
Y el TextBlock será algo como esto:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Resultado}"/>
```

Ahí el TextBlock ya sabe que tiene que mostrar el valor de "Resultado" que está en el ViewModel que definiste arriba, luego, esa variable "Resultado" sería un `String` que está en el ViewModel (o un `Int`, eso lo ves tu), algo así:

```
private string _resultado = string.Empty;
public string Resultado
{
    get { return _resultado ; }
    set { _resultado = value; }
}
```

Y cuando pulsas un botón en el VIEW deberías llamar, mediante un ICommand a tu método de cálculo, que debería, a su vez, setear la Propiedad "Resultado"

```
private void CalcularAction()
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.DocumentoID))
    {// aca enviar al textbox del view txtValor.text = 
        CalcularConceptoPPA(this.DocumentoID, this.concepto.DiasMes, this.concepto.DiasAtraso, this.concepto.Porcentaje, this.concepto.TipoPPA, this.concepto.TCRM);

        Resultado = "EL VALOR";
    }//.... demas codigo
}
```

Con eso bastaría, a menos que no sepas usar ICommands, pero eso es para otra pregunta, y debes recordar aplicar INotifyPropertyChanged para comunicar los cambios del ViewModel al View.. sino aunque hagas mil cosas la pantalla no hará nada.

Edit:
Te dejo la implementación de INotifyPropertyChanged

```
#region Implementación de INotifyPropertyChanged
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

#endregion
```

Y "Resultado" quedaría así:

```
private string _resultado = string.Empty;
public string Resultado
{
    get { return _resultado ; }
    set 
    { 
    _resultado = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged("Resultado");
    }
}
```

Ahora bien, me cuesta un poco entender tu implementación pues parece que estás mezclando patrones.

Y así se hace más menos..
Si te quedan dudas por favor amplía un poco más tu pregunta y con gusto mejoraré la respuesta.

Un saludo :)

Comment: SI efectivamente uso MVVM

Comment: se tiene el metodo que invoca el servicio  lo agregue a la pregunta